# How to add a library in Intellij Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, andengine

I recently switched from Eclipse to Intellij. Now I'm trying to use the andengine library.

In Eclipse it was easy to add libraries. Just right click > properties > add library.

In Intellij there is no option when you right click a folder (see image). How can I add a project library (a folder, not a jar file) in Intellij?

[image]

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to `File > Project Structure`, select `Modules`, and hit the plus button to add another folder (with source code).

Answer (score 0):

Directly to the game engine to add to the project (intelliJ IDEA all versions);

1. Create new project or open existing project.
2. Right click "Java" folder in the project explorer and create New -> Package.
3. Enter new package name: org.andengine
4. [Click to download the AndEngine](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/archive/GLES2.zip)
5. Extract zip file and open AndEngine-GLES2 folder. Follow the path and copy the folder (src -> org -> copy andengine folder).
6. Open your projects and follow the path. Your project module name -> src -> main -> java -> org -> andengine. Paste it here...

=> Open and check Android Studio. when you write will appear "import org." -> andegine.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:
Click on File in the menu
Select Project Structure from the dropdown (Shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S)
Under Module, click + button and select the jar files.
That's it.