# How to add additional libraries in intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to add a second resource folder but in Intellij.  I can't find it under project structure - modules? Tried links below. I clicked plus sign over to right and it shows option for (jars, libraries, modules) but if I click libraries the screen blinks as if the window doesn't have focus. I tried clicking on and off screen and  restarting IDE.  Please assist. Thx

[How to add a library in Intellij Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332869/how-to-add-a-library-in-intellij-idea)
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are under dependencies and not not sources.  Please try file - project structure - modules - select module from middle or press + button - sources tab - then browse for folder - highlight and mark as appropriate type. I got the same error when under dependencies. Idk why it doesn't let you select that option from dependencies tab but the above steps should work for you. :-)

[image]